# JSON Object java to long

Tags: java, json

i have a json object and want to convert it to an int, but i get different numbers. On the first get the output is 1665750692735 (the right One), but on the getInt the output -696618113. Why?
Ok its because its an long. But how i get the long from the JSON Object?

JSON;

```
{"date":1665750692735,"name":"testDateTwo"}
```

Method:

```
   public void add(JsonObject date) {
    System.out.println((date.get("date")));
    System.out.println((date.getInt("date")));
}
```

Comment: Look at the maximum value for integers which is 2,147,483,647. Then compare this to your value: 1,665,750,692,735. Question: can an integer hold that value? - The first returns the correct value because it's treated as text and not converted to an integer. Hint: you might want to look at a data type that can hold larger values, e.g. `long` or even `BigInteger`.

Comment: You can try to search for integer overflow, then find a suitable replacement for int.

Comment: What is the fully-qualified name of JsonObject?

Comment: Is JsonObject actually this  - `org.json.JSONObject`?

Comment: @Chaosfire Unlikely, because the parameter is type `JsonObject`, not `JSONObject`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Very true, but i was thinking it might be a typo, `JSONObject` does have methods `get("")` and `getInt("")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the maximum value of an int is 2147483647,When long converts int, a data overflow occurs